# unable to select items under swing/awt category in jdeveloper

Tags: java, oracle, swing, jdeveloper

I want to create a "java desktop application" project under the category of applications in JDeveloper and then I want to add some swing items to this project.
The first part goes well after creating project when I right click on project name and go to new then application a new window opens but when I go to swing/awt category to add an item to my project, these are unable to select even I am running JDeveloper in studio developer role where all the features are included. 
I am currently using Oracle JDeveloper 12c (12.1.3.0.0).
 Can anyone tell me why these items are unable to select?

Answer (score 0):

Run JDeveloper Studio in default mode.
Then create a new application of type "Java Desktop Application" then your project should be set to work with swing.

Comment: I have done the same thing but unable to select the swing items.